# A pair of dice is rolled repeatedly until it turns up doubles for the 9th time.

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-distribution

> A pair of dice is rolled repeatedly until it turns up doubles for the 9th time.
>
> a) Write the probability mass function for the number of rolls until this happens.
>
> b) What is the probability it will take exactly 50 rolls (rounded to the nearest percent)?

I have tried: `(nC9)(5/6)^n-9(1/6)^9`

$$^n\mathsf C_9{(\tfrac 56)}^{n-9}{(\tfrac 16)}^9$$

Comment: (nC9)(5/6)^n-9(1/6)^9

Comment: Edit the original post, @AKhan (As I have done for you)

Comment: appreciate it thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probability of a success (double) is ${6\over 36} = {1\over 6}$
Number of trials until 9 successes is a Negative Binomial random variable with parameters $r=9$ and $p=\frac{1}{6}$

$P(X=n)={n-1\choose r-1}p^r(1-p)^{n-r}$ for $n=r,r+1...$

So for this case:

$P(X=n)={n-1\choose 8}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^9\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n-9}$ for $n=9,10,11...$

$P(X=50)={49\choose 8}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^9\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{41}\approx 3\%$

Comment: very helpful thank you!